# jQuery active class

Tags: jquery, html

I have been ready alot of this in here, but what works for others do not work for me.

I try to get the active class work with bootstrap and jQuery.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="navbar">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="t#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Course</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lon-in"></span>Logg inn</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nav a").find(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
});
```

The first LI is active as it is in the html code. 
When i run this it works great. But then i add f.eks home.php, about.php, services.php in the href's on the LI's it does not work.

When i add something i href it just switches back to active on the first LI.

Anyone has a solution here?

I have tried many solutions in jQuery. F.eks :

```
$(".nav a").on("click", function() {
    $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
});
```

this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.each($('#navbar').find('li'), function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('active', '/' + $(this).find('a').attr('href') == window.location.pathname);
    });
});
```

this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li.active').removeClass('active');
    $('a[href="' + location.pathname + '"]').closest('li').addClass('active');
});
```

And so on. I have no idea why it wont work when i add in the href links.

Comment: try to use `$(this).addClass("active");` instead of `$(this).parent().addClass("active");` .  `$(this)` points already to your a link

Comment: That i have already tried also. It does not work.

Comment: It's because when you add actual href to the page, you click the link, it will then load the new page (meaning any js will be reset to it's original state on the new page).  You either need to add the active class using your server side code or change the client side code to prevent the default action of the link and ajax load the new page in

Comment: Having `#` as the target for your links significantly changes this problem. If your links go to actual URLs (as indicated on a comment below), then please indicate this in the question.

Comment: @SpoonMeiser although not obvious, this is already in the question: "*But then i add f.eks home.php, about.php, services.php in the href's on the LI's it does not work.*"

Comment: Your last code snippet appears to be the closest, add an `alert(location.pathname)` and `alert($(".nav a").first().prop("href"))` to see why they're not matching - it could be the href is being expanded to a full url (with http etc) or your pathname is not what you expect it to be (most likely it has an extra "/" at the start that you're not expecting)

Answer (score 0):

Issue due to page getting refreshed when you click on link. so what i suggest when you click on link find the index of li tag and then store it to local storage or add the index value in URL this will be the reference for adding active class in li tag.

Comment: If `href` is `#` as in the example code, the page won't refresh when the link is clicked

Comment: Code mentioned in above only for example i guess. real scenario would be like below

        <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="service.php">service</a></li>
        <li><a href="product.php">product</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">contact</a></li>

if # in href this consider this as broken link.

Comment: I didn't realy get where you where going here.

Comment: In that case, I retract my comment :) The question should be updated though

Answer (score 0):

I'm asking myself how you're building up your website. We know you have multiple sites like home.php, about.php etc. but are these sites static or dynamic?

**If you use static sites**

If you have static websites, means the navigation is coded down in every single .php file, you can just move the class 'active' to the correct LI on the corresponding file.

**home.php**

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="navbar">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.php">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="courses.php">Course</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lon-in"></span>Logg inn</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**services.php**

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="navbar">
        <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="courses.php">Course</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lon-in"></span>Logg inn</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

etc.

---

**If you use dynamic sites**

But if you're working with dynamic sites, and i guess you do so, means there is one file (index.php) on which you load the data of the current selected site you'll need to have your navigation also in a separate file, like navigation.php

The last thing you need to know is [include_once](http://php.net/manual/de/function.include-once.php)

with this function you'll be able to include your navigation just once. if you click a link the navigation and in my example also the footer are the only parts of the website which would not be reseted to it's default stats. On this way your posted js code will work.

**index.php**

```html
<body>
<?php
 include_once 'navigation.php';
 switch (key($_GET)) {
  case 'home':
   include 'home.php';
   break;
  case 'services':
   include 'services.php';
   break;
  default:
   include '404.php'
   break;
 }
 include_once 'footer.php';
?>
</body>
```

**navigation.php**

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="navbar">
        <li class="active"><a href="?home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="?services">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="?courses">Course</a></li>
        <li><a href="?about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="?contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="?login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lon-in"></span>Log in</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

hope i could help

greetings hyop